# How to calculate -1 modulo 1000000007 in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo

I tried to get the result of -1 modulo 1000000007 using the `%` operator of C++
and [`fmod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) function.
The output is `-1`, but `-1 modulo 1000000007==1000000006`.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plainly said, you took the wrong operator.

C++ and C `%` **is not** modulo, but remainder.

```
assert(a / b * b + a % b == a); // for integral types
```

If `a` is non-negative, modulo and remainder are the same.

Otherwise the return-value is negative, just add `b`.

```
template<class T>
inline constexpr auto
modulo(T a, T b) -> decltype(a%b) {
    auto r = a % b;
    if (r < 0) r += b;
    return r;
}
```

Or (also) for C:

```
#define modulo(a, b) (a % b < 0 ? a % b + b : a % b)
```

For completeness: Before C++11, `a / b` could always round down instead of always to 0, though C++03 already had a note that the next standard would probably mandate rounding to 0.

[See Wikipedia on modulo](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

> Modulo is the remainder of euclidiean division, and always in range 0 <= modulo < divisor

[And on remainder](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#In_programming_languages):

> In mathematics, the remainder is the amount "left over" after performing some computation.

Comment: There is a corresponding definition of `a/b` such that `a/b * b + a%b == a` holds true when `%` does perform the operation you're calling modulo. Prior to C++11 the specific definition of `a/b` and `a%b` was implementation defined. C++11 now specifies that division provides the algebraic quotient truncated toward zero, which rules out `%` being the operation you're calling modulo.

Comment: now i understand the difference. can you show an example usage of modulo in c++

Comment: To cope with `a < 0 && b < 0`, Suggest `if (r<0) { m = r < 0 ? m - r : m + r; }` instead of `if(r<0) r += b;`

Comment: In C the sign of the result of % is the same as the sign of the dividend or zero. For modulo, you'd want the sign to be the same as the sign of the divisor or zero. So you could just xor the sign bits of divisor and the remainder, and if the remainder is not zero and its sign is different, add the divisor to the remainder.

Comment: @Deduplicator - if a is positive and b is negative, then C's remainder is not the same as modulo (which should be in the range {b+1 -> 0} . For example 10%(-3) in C is +1, while 10 modulo (-3) is -2. Mathematically, it would have been better if C rounded division towards negative infinity rather than zero, then remainder would be the same as modulo, but most computers round towards zero, so C just went along with this. Also many C / C++ references refer to % as the modulo operator. APL, a language dating back to the 1960's has the modulo operator correct.

Comment: @Deduplicator - With C's implementation of %, this formula does not work: (a + n*b) % b == (a % b), where n is any signed integer. It does work in APL.

Comment: @Deduplicator - both the sign of dividend and divisor are important. For integer division (truncate to negative infinity) and modulo to correspond, you have the following combinations: +10/+3, quotient = +3, remainder = 1; -10/-3, quotient = +3; remainder = -1; -10/3, quotient = -4, remainder = +2, +10/-3, quotient = +4, remainder = -2. So integer division rounds down to negative infinity, and remainder is zero or has the same sign as divisor. This is how computers with non-restoring signed divide hardware operate.

Comment: @Deduplicator - missed an edit, it's fixed in one place (truncate), but I left calling it round down (which would be floor) in the other place.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo function that handles negative divisors as well as positive divisors:

```
template<class T>
inline constexpr auto
modulo(T a, T b) -> decltype(a%b) {
    auto r = a % b;
    if((b > 0 && r < 0) || (b < 0 && r > 0))
        r += b;
    return r;
}
```